# Request na mesma página com XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, xmlhttprequest

Bom dia,

Estou a utilizar um script com 3 ficheiros.
->index.php (onde é feita a requisição)
->contacto.php (é a pesquisa e tratamento da requisição)
->ajax.js (que lê e carrega o ficheiro contacto.php por XMLHttpRequest)

Problema,
se eu colocar o formulário no ficheiro index.php funciona ás 1000 maravilhas, mas se fizer um pedido no contacto.php não existe resposta.
Ou seja, o pedido tem variáveis de pesquisa onde me mostra o calendário numa determina tarifa e eu preciso fazer um pedido desde a página contacto.php para ler o mês anterior e próximo, após a pesquisa inicial.

Eu já defini variáveis de sessão, com cookies, com actualização de div em javascript e não consigo fazer o pedido desde a página contacto.php.

Alguma ideia ?

ajax.js

```
function CriaRequest() {
     try{
         request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }catch (IEAtual){

     try{
         request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0");
     }catch(IEAntigo){
         try{
             request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }catch(falha){
             request = false;
         }
     }
 }

 if (!request)
     alert("Seu Navegador não suporta Ajax!");
 else
     return request;
 }

 /**
 * Função para enviar os dados
 */
 function getDados() {
 // Declaração de Variáveis
 var nome   = document.getElementById("txtnome").value;
  var ano   = document.getElementById("ano").value;
  var mes   = document.getElementById("mes").value;
 var result = document.getElementById("Resultado");
 var xmlreq = CriaRequest();
 // Exibi a imagem de progresso
 result.innerHTML = '<img src="http://localhost/booking_testes/ajax/loader_8.gif"/>';
 // Iniciar uma requisição
   xmlreq.open("GET", "ajax/contato.php?txtnome=" + nome + "&ano="+ ano + "&mes="+ mes, true);
 // Atribui uma função para ser executada sempre que houver uma mudança de ado
 xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function(){
     // Verifica se foi concluído com sucesso e a conexão fechada (readyState=4)
     if (xmlreq.readyState == 4) {

         // Verifica se o arquivo foi encontrado com sucesso
         if (xmlreq.status == 200) {
             result.innerHTML = xmlreq.responseText;
         }else{
             result.innerHTML = "Erro: " + xmlreq.statusText;
         }
     }
 };
 xmlreq.send(null);
 }
```

contacto.php

```
<?php
session_start();
// Verifica se existe a variável txtnome
if (isset($_GET["txtnome"])) {

$nome = $_GET["txtnome"];
$month =  $_GET['mes'];
$year = $_GET['ano'];
$diaActual=date("j");

if(empty($month)){
    $month=11;
    $year=date("Y");
    $diaActual=date("j");
}
 # Obtenemos el dia de la semana del primer dia
 # Devuelve 0 para domingo, 6 para sabado
 $diaSemana=date("w",mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year))+7;
 # Obtenemos el ultimo dia del mes
 $ultimoDiaMes=date("d",(mktime(0,0,0,$month+1,1,$year)-1));
 $meses=array(1=>"Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", 
 "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre");
 # Obtenemos el ultimo dia del mes
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$senha = "";
$base = "ajax_booking";
 $conexao = mysql_connect($server, $user, $senha) or die("Erro na conexão!");
mysql_select_db($base);
// Verifica se a variável está vazia
if (empty($nome)) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM contato";
} else {
    $nome .= "%";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM contato WHERE nome like '$nome'";
}
sleep(3);
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$cont = mysql_affected_rows($conexao);
// Verifica se a consulta retornou linhas
if ($cont > 0) {
?>

<br />
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5" border="0" class="calendarTable"> 
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="dash_border">Lun</th>
            <th class="dash_border">Mar</th>
            <th class="dash_border">Mer</th>
            <th class="dash_border">Jeu</th>
            <th class="dash_border">Ven</th>
            <th class="weekend dash_border">Sam</th>
            <th class="weekend dash_border">Dim</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tr>
    <?php
        $last_cell=$diaSemana+$ultimoDiaMes;
        // hacemos un bucle hasta 42, que es el máximo de valores que puede
        // haber... 6 columnas de 7 dias
        for($i=1;$i<=42;$i++)
        {
            if($i==$diaSemana)
            {
                // determinamos en que dia empieza
                $day=1;
            }
            if($i<$diaSemana || $i>=$last_cell)
            {
                // celca vacia
                echo '<td onclick=""class="cal_reg_off"> </td>';
            }else{
                // mostramos el dia
                if($day==$diaActual){
                ?>
                    <td style="background-color:#00ECFF;?>"id="<?php echo $i; ?>"  onclick="getLightbox('<?php echo $day; ?>-<?php echo $month; ?>-<?php echo $year; ?>',1);"onmouseover="getElementById('<?php echo $i; ?>').className='mainmenu5';" onmouseout="getElementById('<?php echo $i; ?>').className='cal_reg_on';" class="cal_reg_on"><?php echo $day; ?><div class="cal_text hide-me-for-nojs">80 place(s) disponible(s)</div></td>
                <?php
                }
                else{
                ?>
                    <td id="<?php echo $i; ?>"  onclick="reply_click('<?php echo $day; ?>-<?php echo $month; ?>-<?php echo $year; ?>',1);"onmouseover="getElementById('<?php echo $i; ?>').className='mainmenu5';" onmouseout="getElementById('<?php echo $i; ?>').className='cal_reg_on';" class="cal_reg_on"><?php echo $day; ?><div class="cal_text hide-me-for-nojs">80 place(s) disponible(s)</div></td>
                <?php
                }
                $day++;
            }
            // cuando llega al final de la semana, iniciamos una columna nueva
            if($i%7==0)
            {
                echo "</tr><tr>\n";
            }
        }
        ?>
</table> 
<?php
} else {
    // Se a consulta não retornar nenhum valor, exibi mensagem para o usuário
    echo "Não foram encontrados registros!";
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Os ficheiros php estão na mesma diretoria? algum erro no php ou no javascript? Podes colocar o php e javascript que estás a usar na pergunta?

Comment: tudo na mesma página, já utilizei url com http e sem url.
Segue o código:

Comment: isto está apenas na versão de teste sem pdo e afins..